# Are these stats reasonable? If not, where should I start?

Tags: mysql, performance, performance-tuning

The below is the output result of mysqladmin for our mysql server which has been having consistent problems for months since we switched from a dedicated server to the cloud.  In the switch, we changed some tuning parameters, and it seems possible that one of these parameters was messed up.  I'm the defacto DBA, but don't know much.  I'm trying to figure out how to interpret the below:

```
Server version      5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-log
Uptime:         117 days 22 hours 28 min 44 sec

Threads: 29  Questions: 1969788526  Slow queries: 143857  Opens: 11865506181  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 512  Queries per second avg: 193.311
```

+------------------------------------------------+--------

| Aborted_clients                               | 416
| Aborted_connects                              | 1639
| Binlog_cache_disk_use                         | 71808
| Binlog_cache_use                              | 21395190
| Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use                    | 0
| Binlog_stmt_cache_use                         | 93
| Bytes_received                                | 1354770670850
| Bytes_sent                                    | 3602027204751
| Com_admin_commands                            | 13164
| Com_assign_to_keycache                        | 0
| Com_alter_table                               | 71
| Com_analyze                                   | 1
| Com_begin                                     | 12066261
| Com_binlog                                    | 0
| Com_change_db                                 | 137117
| Com_commit                                    | 22424711
| Com_create_table                              | 2
| Com_create_trigger                            | 0
| Com_create_udf                                | 0
| Com_create_user                               | 1
| Com_create_view                               | 0
| Com_dealloc_sql                               | 70
| Com_delete                                    | 277919
| Com_delete_multi                              | 0
| Com_do                                        | 0
| Com_drop_db                                   | 0
| Com_drop_event                                | 0
| Com_drop_function                             | 0
| Com_drop_index                                | 0
| Com_drop_procedure                            | 0
| Com_drop_server                               | 0
| Com_drop_table                                | 0
| Com_drop_trigger                              | 0
| Com_drop_user                                 | 0
| Com_drop_view                                 | 0
| Com_empty_query                               | 0
| Com_execute_sql                               | 74
| Com_explain_other                             | 0
| Com_flush                                     | 119
| Com_get_diagnostics                           | 0
| Com_grant                                     | 3
| Com_ha_close                                  | 0
| Com_ha_open                                   | 0
| Com_ha_read                                   | 0
| Com_help                                      | 0
| Com_insert                                    | 105344680
| Com_insert_select                             | 259735
| Com_install_plugin                            | 0
| Com_kill                                      | 8
| Com_load                                      | 0
| Com_lock_tables                               | 6
| Com_optimize                                  | 0
| Com_preload_keys                              | 0
| Com_prepare_sql                               | 74
| Com_purge                                     | 0
| Com_purge_before_date                         | 0
| Com_release_savepoint                         | 0
| Com_rename_table                              | 0
| Com_rename_user                               | 0
| Com_repair                                    | 0
| Com_replace                                   | 1
| Com_replace_select                            | 0
| Com_reset                                     | 0
| Com_resignal                                  | 0
| Com_revoke                                    | 0
| Com_revoke_all                                | 0
| Com_rollback                                  | 28394
| Com_rollback_to_savepoint                     | 0
| Com_savepoint                                 | 0
| Com_select                                    | 1502927854
| Com_set_option                                | 50365426
| Com_signal                                    | 0
| Com_show_binlog_events                        | 0
| Com_show_binlogs                              | 4
| Com_show_charsets                             | 7149
| Com_show_collations                           | 7149
| Com_show_create_table                         | 101370273
| Com_show_create_trigger                       | 0
| Com_show_databases                            | 8
| Com_show_engine_logs                          | 0
| Com_show_engine_mutex                         | 0
| Com_show_engine_status                        | 27
| Com_show_events                               | 0
| Com_show_errors                               | 0
| Com_show_fields                               | 101370995
| Com_show_function_code                        | 0
| Com_show_function_status                      | 0
| Com_show_grants                               | 4
| Com_show_keys                                 | 589
| Com_show_master_status                        | 2
| Com_show_open_tables                          | 0
| Com_show_plugins                              | 0
| Com_show_privileges                           | 0
| Com_show_procedure_code                       | 0
| Com_show_procedure_status                     | 0
| Com_show_processlist                          | 5
| Com_show_profile                              | 0
| Com_show_profiles                             | 0
| Com_show_relaylog_events                      | 0
| Com_show_slave_hosts                          | 4
| Com_show_slave_status                         | 6
| Com_show_status                               | 38
| Com_show_storage_engines                      | 4
| Com_show_table_status                         | 136
| Com_show_tables                               | 88
| Com_show_triggers                             | 116
| Com_show_variables                            | 7287
| Com_show_warnings                             | 8047
| Com_show_create_user                          | 0
| Com_shutdown                                  | 0
| Com_group_replication_start                   | 0
| Com_group_replication_stop                    | 0
| Com_stmt_execute                              | 74
| Com_stmt_close                                | 72
| Com_stmt_fetch                                | 0
| Com_stmt_prepare                              | 74
| Com_stmt_reset                                | 0
| Com_stmt_send_long_data                       | 0
| Com_truncate                                  | 0
| Com_uninstall_plugin                          | 0
| Com_unlock_tables                             | 6
| Com_update                                    | 57786921
| Com_update_multi                              | 0
| Com_xa_commit                                 | 0
| Com_xa_end                                    | 0
| Com_xa_prepare                                | 0
| Com_xa_recover                                | 0
| Com_xa_rollback                               | 0
| Com_xa_start                                  | 0
| Com_stmt_reprepare                            | 0
| Compression                                   | OFF
| Connections                                   | 29435898
| Created_tmp_disk_tables                       | 114402068
| Created_tmp_files                             | 38275
| Created_tmp_tables                            | 2504646759
| Delayed_errors                                | 0
| Delayed_insert_threads                        | 0
| Delayed_writes                                | 0
| Flush_commands                                | 1
| Handler_commit                                | 1757942766
| Handler_delete                                | 52633379
| Handler_discover                              | 0
| Handler_external_lock                         | 27091706448
| Handler_mrr_init                              | 0
| Handler_prepare                               | 342205456
| Handler_read_first                            | 4803251242
| Handler_read_key                              | 4225308943902
| Handler_read_last                             | 40865194
| Handler_read_next                             | 6485209270841
| Handler_read_prev                             | 10366415789
| Handler_read_rnd                              | 171538509
| Handler_read_rnd_next                         | 3848495865600
| Handler_rollback                              | 48600
| Handler_savepoint                             | 0
| Handler_savepoint_rollback                    | 0
| Handler_update                                | 87510208
| Handler_write                                 | 1055828705804
| Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status                | Dumping of buffer pool 
not started               |

| Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status                | Buffer pool(s) load 
completed at 181025  2:58:45 |

| Innodb_buffer_pool_resize_status              |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data                 | 313229
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data                 | 5131943936
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty                | 978
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty                | 16023552
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed              | 8590250
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free                 | 8262
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc                 | 6149
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total                | 327640
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd             | 0
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead                 | 303530
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted         | 0
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests              | 26856935971072
| Innodb_buffer_pool_reads                      | 304296
| Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free                  | 0
| Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests             | 4292568734
| Innodb_data_fsyncs                            | 31123982
| Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs                    | 0
| Innodb_data_pending_reads                     | 0
| Innodb_data_pending_writes                    | 0
| Innodb_data_read                              | 10002846208
| Innodb_data_reads                             | 610655
| Innodb_data_writes                            | 38339619
| Innodb_data_written                           | 397157095424
| Innodb_dblwr_pages_written                    | 8390289
| Innodb_dblwr_writes                           | 543675
| Innodb_log_waits                              | 0
| Innodb_log_write_requests                     | 196703019
| Innodb_log_writes                             | 29155331
| Innodb_os_log_fsyncs                          | 29182283
| Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs                  | 0
| Innodb_os_log_pending_writes                  | 0
| Innodb_os_log_written                         | 118934181888
| Innodb_page_size                              | 16384
| Innodb_pages_created                          | 382512
| Innodb_pages_read                             | 610519
| Innodb_pages_written                          | 8590462
| Innodb_row_lock_current_waits                 | 0
| Innodb_row_lock_time                          | 7111105
| Innodb_row_lock_time_avg                      | 4320
| Innodb_row_lock_time_max                      | 51061
| Innodb_row_lock_waits                         | 1646
| Innodb_rows_deleted                           | 52633379
| Innodb_rows_inserted                          | 2211335475
| Innodb_rows_read                              | 12988670090784
| Innodb_rows_updated                           | 62207650
| Innodb_num_open_files                         | 127
| Innodb_truncated_status_writes                | 0
| Innodb_available_undo_logs                    | 128
| Key_blocks_not_flushed                        | 0
| Key_blocks_unused                             | 53585
| Key_blocks_used                               | 8
| Key_read_requests                             | 2077
| Key_reads                                     | 184
| Key_write_requests                            | 684
| Key_writes                                    | 20
| Last_query_cost                               | 0.000000
| Last_query_partial_plans                      | 0
| Locked_connects                               | 0
| Max_execution_time_exceeded                   | 0
| Max_execution_time_set                        | 0
| Max_execution_time_set_failed                 | 0
| Max_used_connections                          | 37
| Max_used_connections_time                     | 2018-11-27 20:52:01
| Not_flushed_delayed_rows                      | 0
| Ongoing_anonymous_transaction_count           | 0
| Open_files                                    | 3
| Open_streams                                  | 0
| Open_table_definitions                        | 343
| Open_tables                                   | 512
| Opened_files                                  | 859373
| Opened_table_definitions                      | 488
| Opened_tables                                 | 11867165737
| Performance_schema_accounts_lost              | 0
| Performance_schema_cond_classes_lost          | 0
| Performance_schema_cond_instances_lost        | 0
| Performance_schema_digest_lost                | 0
| Performance_schema_file_classes_lost          | 0
| Performance_schema_file_handles_lost          | 0
| Performance_schema_file_instances_lost        | 63
| Performance_schema_hosts_lost                 | 0
| Performance_schema_index_stat_lost            | 0
| Performance_schema_locker_lost                | 0
| Performance_schema_memory_classes_lost        | 0
| Performance_schema_metadata_lock_lost         | 0
| Performance_schema_mutex_classes_lost         | 0
| Performance_schema_mutex_instances_lost       | 0
| Performance_schema_nested_statement_lost      | 0
| Performance_schema_prepared_statements_lost   | 0
| Performance_schema_program_lost               | 0
| Performance_schema_rwlock_classes_lost        | 0
| Performance_schema_rwlock_instances_lost      | 0
| Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost | 0
| Performance_schema_socket_classes_lost        | 0
| Performance_schema_socket_instances_lost      | 0
| Performance_schema_stage_classes_lost         | 0
| Performance_schema_statement_classes_lost     | 0
| Performance_schema_table_handles_lost         | 0
| Performance_schema_table_instances_lost       | 0
| Performance_schema_table_lock_stat_lost       | 0
| Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost        | 0
| Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost      | 0
| Performance_schema_users_lost                 | 0
| Prepared_stmt_count                           | 0
| Qcache_not_cached                             | 26282360
| Queries                                       | 1983838412
| Questions                                     | 1983825241
| Select_full_join                              | 2510
| Select_full_range_join                        | 0
| Select_range                                  | 133055836
| Select_range_check                            | 0
| Select_scan                                   | 4834557364
| Slow_launch_threads                           | 0
| Slow_queries                                  | 144451
| Sort_merge_passes                             | 8779
| Sort_range                                    | 5238452
| Sort_rows                                     | 344471904
| Sort_scan                                     | 24075234
| Table_locks_immediate                         | 11412632
| Table_locks_waited                            | 0
| Table_open_cache_hits                         | 1881438893
| Table_open_cache_misses                       | 11867165733
| Table_open_cache_overflows                    | 11867164202
| Tc_log_max_pages_used                         | 0
| Tc_log_page_size                              | 0
| Tc_log_page_waits                             | 0
| Threads_cached                                | 3
| Threads_connected                             | 26
| Threads_created                               | 1761
| Threads_running                               | 4
| Uptime                                        | 10254430
| Uptime_since_flush_status                     | 10254430

Comment: The problem is lagging on the front end.  Queries have slowed down significantly and the result is a 20-50x slowdown on the front end.  We have a chat that used to update every 200ms that now takes up to 10 seconds (yes I know using mysql for chat is a bad idea, and we're working on that, but that doesn't explain the global slowdown)

Comment: I need to see `SHOW VARIABLES` and how much RAM you have; then I can critique it.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; to pastebin.com and share the links with us.  How much RAM does your server have available?

Comment: @scl Any chance you can post to pastebin.com and share the pastebin link for the results of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; ?    And how much RAM is on the server?  Disclaimer: I am the author of www.mysqlservertuning.com listed in my profile, Network profile.

Comment: @scl  Posting SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; to pastebin.com and sharing the link would allow specific tuning Suggestions to improve your instance performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After increasing the [table_open_cache](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_table_open_cache) until the rate of the statistic `Table_open_cache_misses` / `Table_open_cache_overflows` stays largely still for a minute.

After that you'll need to look at the queries in your slow query log. Statistics (`Handler_read_rnd_next`) shows a large number of full range scans. Which cannot be fixed by tuning.

You rarely can tune yourself out of a performance problem.